# Skip remaning mocha describe it blocks on any it block failure

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

Sometimes our mocha tests fail in the middle of a `describe` on some random `it` block.  All subsequent `it` blocks will fail too.  `--bail` is not a good option since it will bail the entire test suite.  Is there another option that will skip the rest of the `it` blocks in the `describe` and move to the next `describe`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .skip() in this use-case to retroactively avoid a block of tests. 
you can skip a whole describe block like this:

```
  describe.skip('#indexOf()', function() {
    // ...
  });
```

or a single assertion like this:

```
  it.skip('should return -1 unless present', function() {
    // ...
  });
```

It is not currently possible to skip over a failed block once it has failed in a dynamic way.

Comment: Since I don't know which it block will fail I need this to be done dynamically

Comment: I have done some further reading and testing. If a test has already failed, it is impossible to skip(), as Mocha is designed so that an error in any of the hooks terminates testing right away.